# count number of lines in terminal output

Tags: bash, terminal

couldn't find this on SO. I ran the following command in the terminal:

```
>> grep -Rl "curl" ./
```

and this displays the list of files where the keyword curl occurs. I want to count the number of files. First way I can think of, is to count the number of lines in the output that came in the terminal. How can I do that?

Comment: grep itself also has the `-c` flag which just returns the count

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248245/how-to-count-the-number-of-lines-of-an-output

Comment: `grep -Ric "searchpattern" ./` if recursive search/count is required.

Answer (score 645, accepted):

Pipe the result to [`wc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_%28Unix%29) using the `-l` (*line count*) switch:

```
grep -Rl "curl" ./ | wc -l
```

Comment: I've been using `grep "" -c` but this is some much nicer :)

Comment: It should be noted that this trick of piping to wc will work for any output, not just grep output.  For example, it can be combined with a git diff.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? As some comments mentioned the build in function `grep -c` should be used instead of piping the output to another programm. E.g. you would even not changing characters in your Word document with another text editor than Word, would you?

Comment: This is the accepted answer because the question asks generally how to count lines of terminal output. `grep -c` doesn't answer that.

Answer (score 66):

Putting the comment of EaterOfCode here as an answer.

> grep itself also has the -c flag which just returns the count

So the command and output could look like this.

```
$ grep -Rl "curl" ./ -c
24
```

**EDIT:**

Although this answer might be shorter and thus might seem better than the accepted answer (that is using `wc`). I do not agree with this anymore. I feel like remembering that you can count lines by piping to `wc -l` is much more useful as you can use it with other programs than `grep` as well.

Answer (score 21):

Piping to 'wc' could be better IF the last line ends with a newline (I know that in this case, it will)
However, if the last line does not end with a newline 'wc -l' gives back a false result.

**For example:**

```
$ echo "asd" | wc -l
```

Will return `1` and

```
$ echo -n "asd" | wc -l
```

Will return `0`

---

So what I often use is `grep <anything> -c`

```
$ echo "asd" | grep "^.*$" -c
1

$ echo -n "asd" | grep "^.*$" -c
1
```

This is closer to reality than what `wc -l` will return.

Comment: Is it a problem that there  is a tab character at the start of the output of `wc -l`?

Comment: You'll also get a false count if there are no rows but only a new line using wc -l; better to use grep with -c

Answer (score 3):

`"abcd4yyyy" | grep 4 -c` gives the count as `1`

Comment: Not clear what this adds, which other answers hadn't already said better, near 6 years earlier.

Answer (score 0):

There is a case that is not being taken into account in the previous answers I found.

When trying to count the visual lines being printed in the output `wc -l` is not enough, as it does not account for line wrapping.

e.g. In the following example you can see 1 line being printed. But because the window is very tiny, it takes 3 lines of output.

[image]

This is specially useful when trying to remove the previous output and overwrite it with new one.

For this case I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996354/5150227

The original solution has some bugs. Therefor, the final result would look like this:

```
# Lines being printed
printf "%s" "$TAIL_BUFFER"

seenlines=0
cols=$( tput cols )
while IFS= read -r line; do
  # Remove non-printable characters from the line
  lineOfPrintedCharacters=$(echo "$line" | tr -dc '[[:print:]]')

  # Get length of the line in characters,
  # subtracting the newline:
  newLength=$(( $( wc -m <<< "$lineOfPrintedCharacters" ) - 1 ))

  # Add at least one line, and one for each time the line length 
  # exceeds the column size of the terminal
  seenlines=$( bc <<< "$seenlines + 1 + ${newLength} / ${cols}" )

  # Do not remove lines that finish exactly at the edge of the terminal
  if [[ $(( (${newLength}) % ${cols} )) -eq 0 ]] && [[ $newLength -ne 0 ]]; then
    seenlines=$((seenlines - 1))
  fi
done <<< "$TAIL_BUFFER"

echo "${seenlines} lines seen"
```