# Comparing files then to take the difference and make it a numeric value

Tags: macos, awk, numeric

Im using this command: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' spellingword.txt /tmp/userwords.txt` to compare the two files in hopes that I discover the difference and then turn that difference into a numeric value.

Example would be, when comparing the two files, **userwords.txt** comes back with three words that don't match the **spellingword.txt** - therefor, three lines of those words are presented. Now, I want to take that output and turn it into a number "3".

**UPDATE:**

```
Spellingword.txt 
tall
ball
fall
wall
paul

Userword.txt
tall
ball
fall
wall
pall
```

The end user spelled paul wrong. Now, when comparing the files, i get this result.

```
pall}
```

Then using the `grep -Rl "curl" ./ | wc -l` command, I get a result of `2`, when it should be `1`. Where is the `}` coming from?
Any ideas? Or am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: Please, post sample of said files and expected output.

Comment: So you want to [count number of lines in terminal output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12457457/2088135)?

Comment: @JamesBrown Not sure why that matters - the enduser is unpredictable. The output varies base on user input.

Comment: @TomFenech how do i get this command `grep -Rl "curl" ./ | wc -l` to work off a variable? the output varies due to enduser input.

Comment: @EdMorton - I've updated my question..please advise.

Comment: @EdMorton You're right. When running the script, i get this error: `line 249: syntax error near unexpected token `!'
line 249: `wword="$(awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{if(!($0 in a))c++;}END{print c+0}' spellingwords.txt /tmp/userwords.txt)"'`

Comment: @EdMorton if there are problems with my answer, I'm all ears. We're all here to learn and help others right?

Comment: @miken32 don't ask me, I haven't examined your answer, I was just giving the OP general feedback on the wisdom/possible consequences of immediately accepting the first answer they get.

Comment: @JamesDean looks like you have a spurious `'` at the end of the command you show in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

My `userwords.txt` (annotated):

```
tall  # match
ball  # match  
fall  # match
wall  # match
pall  # no match
paul} # partial match
```

The code:

```
$ awk '                      
NR==FNR {                    # hash the first file
    a[$1]
    next
}
{
    if($1 in a)               # search for full match
        next                  # skip to next record if there was a match, else:
    for(i in a)               # loop thru all entries in hash
        if($1 ~ i || i ~ $1)  # search for partial match
            next              # skip to next record if there was a match, else
    c++                       # count misses
} 
END { 
    print c                   # print miss count
}' spellingword.txt /tmp/userwords.txt
1                             # this was the output for "pall"
```

The only improvement was to search for "partial matches", ie. comparing `paul` and `paul}` is a hit, then again clear typo `pual` would not match `paul`. If you would like to catch those as well I'd recommend trying out approximate pattern matching tool [`agrep`](https://github.com/Wikinaut/agrep)and use that for detecting typos with adequate parameters.